# Why does elements in the parabolic subgroups of $SL(n,k)$ take the form of upper block triangular matrices?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be either $SL(n,k)$ (or I guess any linear subgroup of $GL(n,k)$) for a field $k$. And $P$ be a [parabolic subgroup](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Edav/glnpar.pdf) of $G$, I have seen the fact that any $A\in P$ looks like the block diagonal matrix:

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} A_1 & * & * \\ 0 & \ddots & * \\ 0 & 0 & A_m \end{matrix} \right) $$

But how to prove this fact? Any solution or reference will be appreciated!

Comment: An appropriate answer to this depends on your context. If nothing else, you'd probably want to say either that "every parabolic is _conjugate_ to" a block upper-triangular subgroup of the sort you mention, or that these are the "standard parabolic subgroups". How do _you_ define "parabolic..."?

Comment: See 9. in the lecture [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/surp2015/lec0701.pdf), together with some good references.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to show that the set of  upper triangular matrices $B$ of $G= \operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ forms a Borel subgroup of $G$?  This follows from the Lie-Kolchin theorem.

A parabolic subgroup of $G$ is by definition a subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that $gPg^{-1}$ contains $B$ for some $g \in G$.  So what you want to show is that all subgroups of $G$ containing $B$ are of the block diagonal form.

If you let $T$ be the group of diagonal matrices in $G$, and $N$ the normalizer of $T$ in $G$, this follows by showing that $(G,B,N)$ form a [Tits system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(B,_N)_pair).  In any Tits system, the subgroups of $G$ containing $B$ are completely classified in terms of the Weyl group $N/(B \cap N)$.  If you write out what these are, you will see they all take the form you want.